# Cross product of 2d vectors

Tags: matlab, vector, geometry, coordinates, cross-product

I have two coordinate vectors:

```
coor1 = [4 2];
coor2 = [4.3589 1];
```

and I want to find the angle of the rotation, where mathematically it is given by the equation:

[image]

where the numerator is the cross product between the two coordinate pairs and the denominator is the dot product.

The problem is that in MATLAB, a cross product isn't possible with 2-element vectors. Running the following code:

```
ang = atan2(norm(cross(coor1,coor2)),dot(coor1,coor2));
```

produces this error:

```
Error using cross
A and B must be of length 3 in the dimension in which the cross product is taken.
```

Is there any way to make `cross` work? Working this out by hand, the angle of the rotation of both coordinate should be `13.6441`.

Comment: What about `rad2deg(atan2(coor2(2)*coor1(1)-coor2(1)*coor1(2), dot(coor1,coor2)))`?

Comment: @avermaet `rad2deg(atan2(...))` is unnecessary, one can simply use `atan2d` instead.

Comment: Any reason why you're not accepting an answer?

Comment: @Dev-iL my bad, totally forgotten about that. Wish i could accept all answers as they're all valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use the inverse cosine (arccos) instead?

```
coor1 = [4 2];
coor2 = [4.3589 1];

% normalize the vectors:
d1 = coor1 ./ norm(coor1);
d2 = coor2 ./ norm(coor2);

ang = acosd(dot(d1,d2));
```

Comment: `atan2` is a 4-quadrant angle, `acos` a 2-quadrant angle. If the sign of the angle is not needed, this answer is simpler.

Answer (score 5):

Convert vectors to complex numbers and use [angle](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/angle.html):

```
x=coor1 * [1; 1i];
y=coor2 * [1; 1i];
ang = angle(x*y')
```

Other vectorized solution that can convert multiple vectors:

```
atan2(coor1 * (coor2(:,[2,1]).*[1 -1]).',coor1 * coor2.')
```

*Thanks to @Dev-iL  I changed `i` to `1i`.

Comment: Nice one! Complex arithmetic simplifies so many things with 2D vectors.

Comment: Its better to use `1i` to avoid possible issues related to redefinition of `i`, commonly used as loop index.

Answer (score 4):

You can append a zero to the vectors to make them 3D, and then get the 3rd element from the normal vector:

```
n = cross([coor1 0], [coor2 0]);
theta = atan2(n(3),dot(coor1,coor2));
```

Comment: thanks! Is there any reason why Matlab only allows 3D vector?

Comment: @Maxxx why not define your own function that computes cross for 2d vectors? You can call it `cross2d`.

Comment: @Maxxx: The cross product only has a unique definition in 3D. Extensions to other dimensionalities are ambiguous.

Comment: This answer is good if computational cost is not relevant. But this solution does 3 times as many multiplications and additions as directly implementing the formula for 2D cross product (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57890014/cross-product-of-coordinate-vector#comment102202196_57890014).

Comment: @Dev-iL I would say I got too used on using matlab's built in function that i forgot about defining functions for tasks like this.

Comment: @Cris Luengo I see. So with just [x,y] coordinates, the cross function isn't really for [x,y] alone but rather [x,y,z].

Comment: @Maxxx: One way of extending the cross product to 2D (which is what you need to compute the angle between vectors) is to assume z=0, as rinkert does in this answer. In this case, the resulting 3D vector is [0,0,a], with a the one value you're interested in. But there are other ways to extend the cross product to 2D. In principle, the cross product is a 3D concept.

Answer (score 4):

With:

```
x = [4 2];
y = [4.3589 1];
```

You can use the determinant

```
ang = atan2d(det([x;y]),dot(x,y))
```

Noticed that since the unit circle is defined counterclockwise, with this example the angle will be negative. Also using the determinant is mathematically/theoretically wrong, but with a matrix `2x2`the result is the same.

Comment: so if i want it to be positive, i just multiply by -1? Because i remember reading somewhere that rotation transformation is counterclockwise, hence it would be better to have a positive angle.

Comment: take the absolute value: `ang = abs(atan2d(det([x;y]),dot(x,y))`, (but you loose an important information).

Comment: @Maxxx One could also provide the inputs in reverse order to get a sense of "angle from `x` to `y`" and "angle from `y` to `x`".

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use an anonymous function to implement it directly like in my comment:

```
cross2 = @(coor1,coor2)(coor2(2)*coor1(1)-coor2(1)*coor1(2))
```

Now you can use it just like a normal function. I think this should be the ideal solution regarding the number of operations but also for reusability.

```
atan2d(cross2(coor1,coor2),dot(coor1,coor2)) % Thanks @Dev-iL
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about this, but it might be better for performance if `cross2` is defined as a "proper" function since MATLAB's JIT compiler could then optimize it - which might not be the case for anonymous functions. Better yet, make the entire angle computation a function and be done with it.